# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreach, foreign-keys, laravel-5

I currently have 4 tables that consist of:

1. Users
2. Providers
3. Projects
4. Project_Bids

I'm trying to query Laravel's eloquent model on a project's table so when the given user visits a link similar to the following:  **example.com/project/{projectid}**

The view uses a foreach loop to loop through all the project bids that are relevant to that project id.

I'm having the issue of being able to display /loop through all the bids and have them render correctly, I have tried using the following:

```
$projectBids = ProjectBids::where('project_id', '=', $projectid)
                            ->get();
```

And I have tried from both these relationships:

```
public function project_bids(){

    return $this->hasMany(ProjectBids::class, 'project_id');

}

public function project_bids(){

    return $this->belongsTo(ProjectBids::class, 'project_id');

}
```

However when I try and loop through the returned database data I can not display the relevant bid unless I manually have use the following:

return $project->project_bids[0]->bid_price;

and specifiy the [0] row or [1] and so on...

Surely there has to be a much easier way of doing this and as a total novice, after watching days of tutorials and videos I'm loosing myself within the functionality, All I am trying to do is reference the project_bids table to retrieve all the bids where the project_id matches the given id then loop through them within the view.

I want to be able to display the bids that are relevant to the project_id and be able to use the method like this:

$project->projectbids->bid_price

Any help is greatly appreciated, I understand that this question is not the best asked question, this is mainly due to spending 36 hours or more trying to resolve it so my mind is boggled with the amount of tutorials I have tried to follow.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the project with Project with:

```
$project = Project::with('project_bids')->find($id); //id is the id from URL
```

Now you can loop through the bids in the blade:

```
@foreach($project->project_bids as $bids)

@endforeach
```

If you just want the first bid, you can use:

```
$project->project_bids->first()->bid_price;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have many record related to Project, it's obvious you cannot do something like this:

```
$project->projectbids->bid_price
```

because `projectbids` here is not a single element but collection of elements.

To get all the bids, you need to use loop:

```
@foreach ($project->projectbids as $bid) 
   {{ $bid->bid_price }}
@endofreach
```

Comment: Marcin, thank you for taking the time out to help i greatly appreciate it, im just having a break from it at the moment as the stress as taken its toll on me! I am greatfull there is help when you need it most, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong. Assuming `User hasMany Project` and `Project hasMany Bid` so for `Project & Bid` relationship you have to declare `hasMany` relationship in your `app\Project` model first, for example:

```
// App\Project.php
public function bids()
{
    rturn $this->hasMany(Bid::class);
}
```

Now, you can do something like this:

```
$projectWithBids = Project::with('bids')
                          ->where('project_id', $projectid)
                          // assuming projects table gas a user_id field
                          ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
                          ->first();
```

So to access them in your view, you'll do something like this:

```
@foreach($project->bids) as $bid)
    {{ $bid->price }}
    {{-- More --}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time out to help, We all have to start off somewhere in the dev world and i can honestly say i have tried my damn best to resolve the issue on my own watching hours of tutorials and reading docs from laravel and laracasts. The fact that your code is rendering with the bids from -->  Project::with('bids')  is far greater than what i have been able to think of, i knew there was much better ways its just a hard hoop to get through when you have no framework experience. I will attempt to get the above working now, Thankyou i greatly appreciate your time.

Comment: You are welcome, btw, I've updated the answer, I made a mistake :-)

Comment: No problem i am just doing some little touches on the site and i will then give it another try, This is me taking 5 minutes as a break haha! Thanks